# Only want 3 records with the same jobid then skip to the next jobs

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select 8 people from a movie crew. I only want to have 3 producers and then let the query continue with other jobs.

This is my query now:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, j.NameEN, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, j.ID AS JobId 
  FROM crew AS c
  LEFT JOIN job AS j ON c.JobID = j.ID
  LEFT JOIN employee AS e ON c.EmployeeID = e.Id
  WHERE c.MovieID = 237038
  ORDER BY j.SortOrder ASC, c.JobID ASC, e.Score DESC
  LIMIT 8
```

How can I achieve selecting only 3 employee's with the same job id?

Sample output

```
EmployeeID NameEN       Firstname     Lastname   JobId 
802        Director     Chris         Columbus   2
5707       Director     David         Yates      2
1705       Director     Mike          Newell     2
175        Director     Alfonso       Cuarón     2
5115       Writer       Steve         Kloves     3
2041       Writer       Michael       Goldenberg 3
11096      Writer       J.K.          Rowling    3
```

You can see here that I have 4 Directors. The desired output would be that there were 3 Directors max.

Comment: Add sample input and desired utput.

Comment: Most DBMSes support `row_number() over (partition by JobId order by ...)` to determine the 1st three per job.

Comment: How do you know, which Directors you need to get from four of them (get the three)

Comment: @D-Shih Because of the ordering on their score. I just need to skip getting the last one so there is a space left for another employee with a different jobId that doesn't have a maxcount of 3.

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: @D-Shih 5.6.16-1.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is only available in MySQL 8.0 upwards

Comment: @Nick Yeah i figured...

Comment: A result set without a data set is like a stick without a lollipop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: You can [emulate row_number() functionality](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) in older versions of MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method for your particular problem is `union all`:

```
(SELECT EmployeeID, j.NameEN, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, j.ID AS JobId 
 FROM crew c LFT JOIN
      job j
      ON c.JobID = j.ID LEFT JOIN
      employee e
      ON c.EmployeeID = e.Id
 WHERE c.MovieID = 237038 AND
       j.NameEN = 'Producer'
 ORDER BY j.SortOrder ASC, c.JobID ASC, e.Score DESC
 LIMIT 3
) UNION ALL
(SELECT EmployeeID, j.NameEN, e.Firstname, e.Lastname, j.ID AS JobId 
 FROM crew c LFT JOIN
      job j
      ON c.JobID = j.ID LEFT JOIN
      employee e
      ON c.EmployeeID = e.Id
 WHERE c.MovieID = 237038 AND
       j.NameEN <> 'Producer'
 ORDER BY j.SortOrder ASC, c.JobID ASC, e.Score DESC
 LIMIT 5
);
```